# Makefile stuck after segmentation fault

Tags: ubuntu, makefile

I have the following makefile rule

```
$(OUTDIR)/%.out: $(EXAMPLE)/%.c .FORCE | $(OUTDIR)
    myprogram $< -o $@

$(OUTDIR):
     mkdir -p $(OUTDIR)
```

I'm using this makefile rule to test my program. I have a range of examples in the example dir and write my output to the outdir. This all works generally fine and helps me a lot to test my application.

The problem is now when I run into a segmentation fault within my program. When I run my program normal in the console it returns segmentation fault and exits. But when I run it from the makefile it does not return segmentation fault but gets stuck within the makefile rule. Make seems to retry it or something like this, it allocates a lot of memory and fills in seconds the whole memory.

Is this a bug of make (I'm using GNU Make 3.81 on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS)? Or does anyone know a way to force make to detect the segmentation fault and report it instead?

**Update**

I tried myself to reproduce the error with a dummy program creating a segmentation fault. I first tried the following program, which obviously creates a segmentation fault.

```
void main(int argc, char **argv){
    int *a = NULL;
    a[0] = 4;
}
```

The make is able to handle this one. It exits like expected and reports a segmentation fault.

The way I could reproduce the problem was with a segmentation fault due to infinite recursion (resulting in a stack overflow) like in this program.

```
int recursive(int i){
  if(i > 0){
    recursive(++i);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  recursive(2);
}
```

With this make fills up the whole memory. It seems that make has somehow unlimited stack size while normally the system limits the stack.

Comment: Tried to recreate your settings, seems work ok for me. May be `make` or your program sets rlimit to make a coredump if segfault occured? What `ulimit -c` says?

Comment: @AndreyStarodubtsev `ulimit -c` returns `0`. I managed to reproduce the error with a simple dummy program and edited the question. Maybe you can try it if you get the same problem?

Comment: Tried, it still works. The same version of GNU make is used, but I run all tests on Mac OS X - maybe that's why they went OK? BTW g++ argues about absent `return` statements in your functions. If you call program from your makefile directly, I mean from phony target without any dependencies, does `make` hang?

Comment: Stack overflows and segmentation faults cause undefined behavior. Trying to figure out *why* they do different things on different machines (or operating systems, or days of the week) is probably labor lost.

Comment: As it seems it the stack size unlimited within the make task. Outside of make `ulimit -s` returns `8192`, within make `unlimited`. When I try to limit it with `ulimit -s 8192` does this have no effect, its still unlimited. Following [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16279867/gmake-change-the-stack-size-limit) it is a bug in make which should be solved in 3.82. So either I'll upgrade my make or try the workaround provided in the other question.